# Alternative formulations for this function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

So we are dealing with a function

$$f(t) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(t - T)^n}{n!} \sum_{m = 1}^{n} \frac{(m - 1)!}{(m + c)!}, \tag{1}$$

defined for all $t \in [0, T]$ and $c \in \mathbb{N}^+$. We know that $f(T) = 0$.

Since we would like to study monotonicity of $f(t)$, perhaps it's better to simplify this function and it appears that one way to do so it through the exponential integral function. If I'm not mistaken, we get

\begin{align}
f(t) = \frac{e^{t - T} \left( (t - T) E_{- c} (t - T) + 1 \right) - 1}{c^2 \Gamma(c)} - \frac{e^{t - T}}{c (t - T)^c}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Now the problem is that $f(T)$ is not defined because for $t = T$, we get $\frac{1}{0}$ in the second term of formulation (2).

I'm having problems explaining this because from (1), $f(T) = 0$ but we don't see that in (2).
Am I missing something? Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(t) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(t - T)^n}{n!} \sum_{m = 1}^{n} \frac{(m - 1)!}{(m + c)!}$$

For the time being, let $x=t-T$ and use the fact that
$$ \sum_{m = 1}^{n} \frac{(m - 1)!}{(m + c)!}=\frac 1{c^2}\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma (c)}-c\frac{ \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (c+n+1)}\right)$$
$$g(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{c^2 \Gamma (c)}-\frac{e^x x^{-c}}{c^2 \Gamma (c)}\Big[\Gamma (c+1)-\Gamma (c+1,x)\Big]$$ Expanded as series around $x=0$
$$g(x)=\frac{c^2+5 c+6 }{\Gamma (c+4)}x\Bigg[1+\frac{c^2+6 c+9 }{2 \left(c^2+5 c+6\right)}x+\frac{c^2+6
   c+11 }{6 \left(c^2+5 c+6\right)}x^2 +O\left(x^3\right) \Bigg]$$ which does not seem to make any problem